# Flipping card with button inside of it

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, flip

I have various cards flipping to display purchase information but because the card flips based on an onClick when the add item button gets pressed it flips the card, is there a way around this or should I look into a different way to display purchase info. heres the html an js

```
<div class="f1_container">
 <div class="shadow f1_card">
  <div class="front face">
   <img src="http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/48/0b/14/dolphin-view-chalets.jpg" />
  </div>
<div class="back face center">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <th>&nbsp;Print Size &nbsp;</th>
     <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Price + Shipping</th>
     <th> &nbsp;&nbsp;Quantity</th>
     <th> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>4x6</td>
     <td>$5.00</td>
     <td><i class="fa fa-minus-square" id="minus"></i> </td>
     <td><i class="fa fa-plus-square" id="plus"></i></td>
    </tr>



$('.f1_container').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$("#plus").on("click", function(event) {
// Preventing the button from trying to submit the form
event.preventDefault();
    console.log("hey this worked");
});
```

Comment: You should `event.stopPropagation()` for the plus click to keep that event from bubbling up to the click handler.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't familiar with that.